# Rewrite cond not carrying arguments .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have a server where i have two django projects, both in different subfolders so i have 
example.com/p1 and example.com/p2

I needed that when the user entered in example.com he was redirected to example.com/p1 but still remaning on example.com.

So i did that with the following code on my .htaccess.:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RedirectMatch 301 ^$ http://example.com/p1/
RewriteRule ^$ /p1/?$ [L]
```

And that is working fine... For the home page but when i go to a sublink say the link is something like this

```
<a href="/foo/">Foo</a>
```

When i click on it it redirects me to example.com/foo/ 
I get why is doing that. Is there a way to make a rule that carries the url?

So say for example when the user came to the link example.com/foo/ it went to example.com/website/foo/ but for the user it showed as example.com/foo/  without havei the specific name of the url on the rule, so that the same rule apllied to both say the urls "foo" and "bar"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Redirect directive here, just use mod_rewrite :

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /p1/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite your urls :

```
http://example.com
```

to

```
http://example.com/p1
```

and

```
http://example.com/foo
```

to

```
http://example.com/p1/foo
```